# Issue loading knockout components view model using requireJS

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-components

I am working with the new components functionality of knockout 3.2 and trying to load the components using requireJS. However, I am having a weird issue. Basically, when I hardcode the view model in the register function everything works fine. When I try to load the exact same view model using requireJS, it's not working correctly.

Here's a sample of the html to load the component:

```
<div data-bind="component: { name: 'test'}"></div>
```

Here's the html in the template that this component will load:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: addNew">add</a>
<span data-bind="visible: Adding">test</span>
```

When I write my register function as shown below, everything works as expected (meaning that when this gets loaded, the "test" text does not show until the user clicks the "add" link):

```
ko.components.register('test',
{
    template: { require: 'text!path/theTemplateFromAbove.html' },
    viewModel:
        function() {
            var self = this;
            self.Adding = ko.observable(false);

             self.addNew = function() {
                 self.Adding(true);
             }
        }
 });
```

But if I try to change this to use requireJS to load the view model, it doesn't work. The "test" text displays immediately without the user clicking the "add" link. The observables on the view model are getting messed up somehow.

Here's the script file contents (note the view model is the same):

```
define(["knockout"], function (ko) {

    function viewModel() {  
        var self = this;
        self.Adding = ko.observable(false);

        self.addNew = function () {
            self.Adding(true);
        }
    };

    return viewModel;
});
```

And the register function would now look like this:

```
ko.components.register('test',
{
    template: { require: 'text!path/theTemplateFromAbove.html' },
    viewModel: { require: 'path/fileForMyTemplate' }
});
```

While debugging the issue, I added a check in the resolveViewModel function of knockout-3.2.0. After it calls new viewModelConfig(params), I check if "Adding" is an observable on the object. When the view model is hardcoded in the register function, it returns true. When I use requireJS to load the view model, it returns false.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: is your `ko.components.register` line wrapped inside a `requirejs` module? I suspect you load javascript file `knockout.js` before `require.js` file, and then you access global `ko` variable to do `ko.components.register`.

Comment: Ah that's the problem. We are loading knockout.js external to requireJS because of other code on the page that relies on it. The component is getting registered with global ko but the script for my view model is using knockout that requireJS loads. Is there a way to make requireJS use the knockout that is already loaded on the page?

Comment: You could do `define(function() { });` and just use global ko inside the function.

Comment: That's what I decided to do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @huocp or elf411 can you file your comment as an answer?

Comment: This was very helpful. `define(function() { ...my view model code... })` instead of `define(function(ko) { ...my view model code... })` did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[copied from comment as a answer to avoid confusion]

Is your `ko.components.register` line wrapped inside a requirejs module?

I suspect you load javascript file `knockout.js` before `require.js` file, and then you access global `ko` variable to do `ko.components.register` which is a different `ko` object from the one loaded by `require.js`.