# Knockout.js: Local Observables within Component ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-components

I'm using knockout's components (loaded via require.js) to create a login widget.

Javascript:

```
ko.components.register('login-widget', {
    viewModel: { require: '/components/login-widget.js' },
    template: { require: 'text!/components/login-widget.html' }
});

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.email = ko.observable();
    self.password = ko.observable();
    self.mode = ko.observable('login');
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <login-widget params="{ email: email, password: password, mode: mode}"></login-widget>
</div>
```

Component Javascript

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
    function LoginWidgetViewModel(params) {
        var self = this;

        self.email = params.email;
        self.password = params.password;

        self.mode = params.mode;
    }
    return LoginWidgetViewModel;
});
```

Component html snippet:

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" data-bind="value:email">
```

This all works fine, but when I try to move the observable into to the LoginWidgetViewModel instead of passing them as parameters, they don't bind correctly to the model. So when I use

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
    function LoginWidgetViewModel(params) {
        var self = this;

        self.email = ko.observable();
        self.password = ko.observable();

        self.mode = ko.observable('login');
    }
    return LoginWidgetViewModel;
});
```

instead of:

[image: Working Login]

I get:

[image: Not working login]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to create a simplified repro but that [works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/049y6qyt/). Perhaps the problem lies with the AMD bits, or perhaps it lies in your actual repro being slightly different from what you posted, not sure. Could you bifurcate between my jsfiddle and your code to track down the root cause and include info on that in your question?

Comment: PS. What you see is in my experience *typically* caused by the actual code being *a function returning an observable* as opposed to an observable itself. See e.g. [this contrived jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c721Lsuk/). Do you have some custom binding handler in your actual code that should be unwrapping an observable, but doesn't?

Comment: I added a local variable like I was trying to do in mine and it worked, so I'm obviously doing something different. Thanks for the help, it's probably something to do with how I'm loading things. http://jsfiddle.net/y21ztg21/

Comment: Yup, it's definitely something to do with how I'm loading it. When I load the view model via require.js it breaks, but when using the view model directly in the component it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was loading knockout and require.js globally, and then loading the viewmodels in using require, which was loading another instance of knockout. I removed the non-require reference to knockout and everything started working how I'd expect it to work.

Found solution over at [Issue loading knockout components view model using requireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515176/issue-loading-knockout-components-view-model-using-requirejs)

Comment: This one caused me much grief! Thanks for updating your own question with the answer.