# HTML with knockout SPA attempt with components, bindings not working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, requirejs, single-page-application

I'm trying to make an SPA website with knockout and requirejs from websites I've seen and tutorials, in order to split up the website so it isn't a single gigantic thing.  At one point I'm expecting to see:

> `My first name is: Bryan`

But instead I'm getting:

> `My first name is: function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.tb(c[E],arguments[0])&&(c.ga(),c[E]=arguments[0],c.fa()),this;a.l.oc(c);return c[E]}`

Starting with my index.thml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>asdf</title>
</head>
<body>
   <mainview></mainview>

   <!-- global imports -->
   <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.min.js"></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.js:

```
"use strict";

requirejs.config({
baseUrl: '',
paths: {
    knockout: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min',
    text: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-text/2.0.12/text.min'
}
});

ko.components.register(
  'mainview', 
  {
    require: './indexViewModel'
  }         
);

ko.applyBindings();
```

indexViewModel.js:

```
"use strict";

define(['knockout', 'text!./indexViewModel.html'], function(ko, htmlString) {
  function indexViewModel(params)
  {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable('Bryan');
  }

  return { viewModel: indexViewModel, template: htmlString };
});
```

Finally my indexViewModel.html:

```html
<div>
    <p>input name: <input data-bind="value: firstName"></input></p>
    <p>My first name is: <span data-bind='text: firstName'></span></p>
</div>
```

All this gives the result I stated above.

Now if I change `firstname` to `firstName()`, then it initially comes up right, but if I change the input, nothing happens.

Comment: and something else, due to another issue I was seeing, in order to get this page working, I've having to use this:   

    #!/bin/bash

    lserver -p 9000 -r ./ -f ./index.html

Comment: You have no argument to `ko.applyBindings`. You want to pass it your viewmodel.

Comment: The way I've done this, I don't have a main viewmodel, that's auto-connected through the knockout component system

Comment: Hmm, if I convert your code to a non-requirejs version [it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/7z4u4gc5/), strange. - PS. As a side note: `input` is either self-closing or void, don't use a seperate closing tag.

Comment: Typically the output you see is what you get if Knockout can somehow no longer see that something is an observable. [For example](https://jsfiddle.net/x0zj2487/) when you'd data-bind `text: ""+firstName`.

Comment: Did you try to remove your knockout script import from the index file and just make requirejs handle the dependencies or the other way around? I can imagine using both ways causes problems.

Comment: Haven't tried any of these suggestions yet (at work), but I was hoping to keep both as I want knockout for the MVVM UI stuff and require to help with pulling in files so I can split things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, with more digging and googling, I happened upon the solution.  I don't get the details, but it's requirejs and knockoutjs are colliding some how

Because on my index.html, I import knockout and I have knockout setup as a requirejs parameter from the config.

I found this
[Issue loading knockout components view model using requireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515176/issue-loading-knockout-components-view-model-using-requirejs)
that clued me in.

ok so I made these changes:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Battlestations Character Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <mainview></mainview>

    <!-- global imports -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.min.js"></script>
    <!-- no more knockout reference here -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

now my index.js:

```
"use strict";

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        knockout:     'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min',
        text: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-text/2.0.12/text.min'
    }
});

// "app main()"
requirejs(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    var self = this;

    ko.components.register(
        'mainview', 
        {
            require: './indexViewModel'
        }         
    );

    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

and changed `<input></input>` to `<input />`, although that changed nothing, but if that's "good practice", I'll go with it.

after those changes, reload, all works, and changing the input changes the `<span>` right after it.
yay!

Comment: The difference between `<input></input>` and `<input/>` is not that one is "good practice", but that the other is incorrect HTML. And in this case, all the browsers just happen to have the same kind of error correction for this error - ignore the `</input>` as if it isn't there - but you should not count on that being the case always.

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer is accepted, Here I am posting an answer just for the users who have tried the answer and failed. I was also experiencing this issue in my MVC application. The problem was, I was referring the `knockout-3.4.0.js` file both in `_Layout.cshtml` and the my page. When I remove the JS reference from `_Layout.cshtml` and reference the same to only to the page, it was all fine. Cheers!