# How to centralize knockout component registration?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, knockout-3.0

**Disclaimer :** Apology for lenghty post as I want to briefly describe my problem.

I have created basic knockout component and it was totally working fine but I came to the point that everytime I want to use my component into other template I need to require it to it's consumer/viewmodel before it works (or else it will complain mycomponent is unknow) which makes me think that it violate DRY principle. Instead I want it to be part of knockout.

Scenario : mycomponent registration

```
/*mycomponent registration */

define(
[
    "knockout",
    "text!components/my-component-template.htm",
    "components/my-component-view-model"
],
function (ko, myComponentTemplate, MyComponentViewModel)
{
    "use strict";

    ko.components.register("mycomponent",
    {
        viewModel:
        {
            createViewModel: function (params)
            {
                return new MyComponentViewModel(params);
            }
        },

        template: myComponentTemplate
    });
});
```

And I use it by requiring it as normal like :

Example 1 :

```
/* template of other consumer */

<ul data-bind='normal knockout function'>
   <li>
     <a href='#sample-only'></a>
     <!-- ko component: { name: "mycomponent", params: { data : $data } } -->
     <!-- /ko -->   
   </li>
</ul>

/* other view model 1*/

define(
[      
    "knockout",
    "mycomponent" --> I want to eliminate this and make it part of knockout
],
function ()
{
    "use strict";
    /* Normal coding stuff here */
});
```

Example 2 : lets pretend this is different for sample purposes

```
/* other template that want to use mycomponent */
<ul data-bind='other template'>
   <li>
     <a href='#sample-only'></a>
     <!-- ko component: { name: "mycomponent", params: { data : $data } } -->
     <!-- /ko -->   
   </li>
</ul>

/* other view model 2 */

define(
[        
    "knockout",
    "mycomponent" --> I want to eliminate this and make it part of knockout
],
function ()
{
    "use strict";
    /* Normal coding stuff here */
});
```

I tried to experiment by understanding how the [custom loader](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html) works and realized none of the examples in the link that instantiate their view model manually via `createViewModel` like my example above. Then, another approach that I thought is much simplier is to create `knockout-extension.js` use it to register my components and other knockout file like custome binding handler etc. and require it in my index.cshtml like below:

```
/* knockout-extension.js */
define(
[        
    "<path>/mycomponent" --> Found in Scenario mycomponent registration above
], 
function()
{
      /* do nothing*/
})


/* Index */

<script type="text/javascript">

 require({
            baseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/js")',
            waitSeconds: 45,
            paths:
            {
                /* 
                . other dependencies here                               
                */
                "knockout" : "<path>/knockback-extensions"
            }
});
```

But this approach lead to load time out problem like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515176/issue-loading-knockout-components-view-model-using-requirejs) which I can't resolve.

Can someone shed me little lights or is this even possible? How could I eliminate repetition of requiring my component every now and then to it's consumer but instead I want it to be part of my knockout. I want to centralize the registration in one single file whithout requiring it to its consumer. As of now it is quite of a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a clue in this [link](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/173) wherein you can require inside define function. This resolve my issue on view model.

```
define(
[
    "knockout"
    "require"        
],
function (ko, require)
{
    "use strict";

    require(
    [
       "components/my-component-view-model"
    ],
    function (MyComponentViewModel)
    {
        ko.components.register("mycomponent",
        {
            viewModel:
            {
                createViewModel: function (params)
                {
                    return new MyComponentViewModel(params);
                }
            },

            template: { require : 'text!template-path-here' }
        });
    });
});
```